# QTimer slot triggered for multiple time?

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qtimer, qt5.12

I'm creating a UI application for Raspberry PI to read data from sensor on definite timeout (5 seconds). Problem is the QTimer timeout slot is called for multiple times

```
{   //at system init
readTempCur = new QTimer(this);
connect(readTempCur, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(readSensor()));
readTempCur->start(SAMPLINGTIME);
readSensor();   //added to call on boot itself, can be removed
}
void HomePage::readSensor(void) {
   readTempCur->stop();
   qDebug() << "Read Sensor triggerred at " <<QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString();
   //DO my actions
   readTempCur->start(SAMPLINGTIME);
 }
```

[image: Screenshot for QTimer triggered multiple times]

[edit for answer]
The most probable case for such issue is conneccting the slot to the signal that already conneccted; this will trigger slot for 'n' number times it got connected, design should take care not to reconnect again.

Comment: Do you want a single-shot for the timer? in your `readSensor` you called the `start` function, this why it will call it again.

Comment: yes I added this to solve whether my slot functions takes execution more than timeout period, 
On beginning I stopped the timer, and after finishing all the jobs, I start the timer again.

Comment: So use one timer for sensor reading and another for execution timeout

Comment: "*Problem is the QTimer timeout slot is called for multiple times*" Yes, of course it is. That's how QTimer works by default. But it is not clear what it is you actually want. Do you only want it to trigger once?

Comment: Here multiple times at same time not on defined timeout, can you see the screenshot, at exactly same time stamp two times it got triggered, ans this is random behavior

Comment: Thanks guys got help from QT people, the sysInit() is called for multiple times which reconnected same slot to same signal once again. I hope fixing that will probably fix this one

Comment: If you are calling `sysInit` multiple times, then you are creating a new timer each time, so you would have multiple timers running.

Answer (score 2):

The [QTimer::start](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#start-1) function will start/restart the timer.

Your `readSensor` function stops the timer and then restart it again.

remove the `start` to fix it.

```
void HomePage::readSensor(void) {
   readTempCur->stop();
   qDebug() << "Read Sensor triggerred at " <<QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString();
   //DO my actions
   //readTempCur->start(SAMPLINGTIME);
 }
```

P.S.
If you want to run the timer once you can use the singleShoot

```
QTimer::singleShot(SAMPLINGTIME, this, SLOT(readSensor()));
```

Comment: sorry this won't work, on beginning, I stopped the timer, even removing the start() and stop() inside the slot function same behavior,
This occurs not on all the call, but randomly, sometimes it is called for 2 times, sometimes it is called for even 4-5 times

Comment: did you try to remove just the `start()`? what is the `SAMPLINGTIME` value?

Comment: I think you will have to provide more code. I can't see the problem here. please update your question [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I also doubt the same, problem should be some where else in the project, but I need some suggestions whether this multiple timeout trigger is possible or not, or it is a bug from Qt12.0

Answer (score 0):

Do not stop nor restart the timer in `readSensor()`. Just do:

```
void HomePage::readSensor(void)
{
    qDebug() << "Read Sensor triggerred at " <<QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString();
    //DO my actions
}
```

Also, make sure `SAMPLINGTIME` is given in milliseconds. For 5 seconds, `SAMPLINGTIME` should be 5000.

Comment: Tried this, but result is same.

Comment: @Kanni1303 Then I'm afraid nobody can help you. The problem lies elsewhere and is not in the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks guys! got help from QT people, the sysInit() is called for multiple times on random; which reconnected same slot to same signal once again. I hope fixing that will probably fix this one